location of zeros of the averaged polynomial
Let $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be points with a given joint distribution on $[a,b]^n$ (e.g., eigenvalue point process of some Hermitian random matrix). Form random polynomial $p(x):=\prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j)$ and take its expected value $q(x):=\mathbb{E}[p(x)]$ with respect to the distribution above.
For non-probabilistic analysts: we define
$$
q(x) = \int_{a}^b\ldots\int_a^b \prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j) \rho(x_1,\ldots,x_n) dx_1\ldots dx_n
$$
for some non-negative function $\rho(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.
It is clear that $q(x)$ has no zeros on $\mathbb{R}\setminus [a,b]$: if $z_0>b$ then $p(z_0)>0$ so that $q(z_0)=\mathbb{E}[p(z_0]>0$, and similarly for $z_0<a$. How to show that there are no complex zeros?
It feels it's related to some convexity argument since for a fixed $z_0\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, we have that $z_0-x$ belongs to the same half-plane for all $x\in[a,b]$. However $p(x)$ is a product of $n$ factors of the form $z_0-x$ and my convexity argument doesn't seem to work out.
More generally, if $[a,b]$ is replaced with some $X\subset\mathbb{C}$, is it true that all of the zeros of $q(x)$ belong to the convex hull of $X$?
